# Determine the interpolating polynomial

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Determine the polynomial of $ deg \le 6 $ interpolating function $$ f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1 $$ at the points : $ -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 $. 
My first idea it was to use Lagrange's formula, but it's too long. 
Maybe you have other, faster method? Because I guess, that I should give only polynomial and maybe Lagrange's formula is not needed. 
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Why do you need a polynomial if you have f(x) which is a polynomial?

Comment: I must determine the polynomial of degree $ \le 6 $ and use points from task.

Comment: The **unique** interpolating polynomial of degree $\le 3$ is $$ p(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1, $$ this has degree $\le 6$.

Comment: @gammatester fine, but I must give other polynomial

Comment: It is **unique**! Obviously you can cheat with $$ p(x) = 0\times x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1 $$

Comment: If you interpolation points are less than 3 then you can give another interpolation polynomial but like this your interpolation polynomial is uniquely determined as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f does interpolate f in $ -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 $ and his degree is lower than 6.

Comment: this is so obvious, thanks for help!